# show full view controller from popover in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I am trying to show a full screen view from a button in a popover view. I tried various codes including the following. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

```
self.view.presentviewcontroller
self.parentview.presentviewcontroller.
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let view2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login") as logInViewController
    self.presentViewController(view2, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks but, it does not work. I get: whose view is not in the window hierarchy!